# Can I use pptp on a vmware virtual machine in the nat mode?

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn, pptp

I installed a Ubuntu 14.10 virtual machine on Windows 8.1 using Vmware.
  Ubuntu has access to Internet in the NAT mode. But I can't establish a pptp connection to a remote server from Ubuntu. Is this supported?

Answer (score 1):

change to bridged (instead of NAT)

Comment: When I try the bridged mode, the virtual machine cannot connect to Internet, let alone use pptp.

Answer (score 0):

I use VMware with a Macbook. I have found that I can use bridged mode with a hard wired connection. Then the virtual machine reports its own unique MAC address and receives its own IP address. After that PPTP works. No luck with WiFi. It must be adapter dependent, though; since I cannot imagine how it would otherwise be different. It is annoying not to be able to use WiFi for the VPN.